# How can I order by sum of three column from different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select username,
(select COUNT(OpenUser) from TIcket t with(nolock) where t.OpenUser = u.UserName and cast(t.CompletedDate as date) = cast(getdate() as date) and t.IssueClass = 58) as ServiceNote,
(select COUNT(AssignUser) from TIcket t with(nolock) where ((t.AssignUser = u.UserName and t.Status = 1) and t.IssueClass != 58)) as status1,
(select COUNT(PickUpUser) from TIcket t with(nolock) where ((t.PickUpUser = u.UserName and t.Status = 2) and t.IssueClass != 58)) as status2
  from users u
  where isinactive = 0
  and UserLevel > -1 and First_Name != '' 
  and center_id = '100'
```

I made query for my program. And I want to order by sum of three field ServiceNote,status1,status2.
I tried to order using 'Sum',(like order by (ServiceNote,status1,status2) but it doesn't work.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If columns are the same (in select statement) you can use union and then order by, but it's not really good

Comment: *I want to order by sum of three field ServiceNote,status1,status2.* If server version allows move the query to CTE and sort by `ServiceNote+status1+status2`. If not add a field with this sum into output list and sort by it.

Comment: Your syntax is not consistent with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
order by (serviceNote + status1 + status2)
```

This works in most databases, but not in SQL Server.  For that, use a CTE or subquery:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*
from cte
order by (serviceNote + status1 + status2);
```

Comment: No. I only gets Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'serviceNote'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'status1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'status2'. => this kind of error

Comment: @YunjeongLim . . . You have mistagged the question.  The `order by` would work in MySQL.  On closer inspection, though, the syntax is not MySQL syntax.  You should correctly tag the question.